# pyqt QFileDialog.getOpenFileName() get path of the directory of the file

Tags: python, directory, pyqt, qfiledialog, getopenfilename

I'm searching for a way to get the path of the directory of the file that I have chosen by `QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()`.
I know that you can access it by `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(filename)`, but I'm searching for a better way because I need to work in this directory.
I don't really understand why you can access the file by `open(filename, 'r')` though your current working directory (when typing `print(os.getcwd())` is not the directory of the file.
Maybe there is a way by accessing something like the current working directory of the Qt.Application, but I had no success..

Also I have functions where you need `arg1 = directory` and `arg2 = filename1` (in the directory) as arguments. Funnily enough they suddenly seem to work with just(!) `arg1 = 'C:'` as directory and `arg2 = filename2` when `filename2` is the file I've accessed by `QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()`.

I'm happy about any explanation!

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that the filename which is accessed by QFileDialog.getOpenFileName() is actually not only the filename but the whole path..